# 2D array of pointers c++ with null pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, initialization

How can I declare a two-dimensional array of pointers and initialize it by null pointers in c++ ?

I tried to do this

```
int *arr[20][30]= nullptr;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [aggregate initialize](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) the array with empty initializer list,

```
int *arr[20][30] {}; 
// or 
int *arr[20][30] = {};
```

(emphasis mine)

> If the number of initializer clauses is less than the number of members `and bases (since C++17)` or initializer list is completely empty, the remaining members `and bases (since C++17)` are initialized `by their default member initializers, if provided in the class definition, and otherwise (since C++14)` by empty lists, in accordance with the usual [list-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) rules (**which performs value-initialization for non-class types and non-aggregate classes with default constructors, and aggregate initialization for aggregates**).

Then all the elements of `arr` (i.e. the sub-array `int* [30]`) would be [aggregate-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) with empty initializer list too, then all the elements of sub-array with type `int*` would be [value-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization),

> otherwise, the object is [zero-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization).

At last elements with type `int*` (which is built-in type) are all zero-initialized to null pointers.

> If `T` is a scalar type, the object's initial value is the integral constant zero [explicitly converted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) to `T`.